# Convert javax.mail.BodyPart object to Json string using java

Tags: java, json, jakarta-mail

I can download attachments from an email account using JavaMail API. During working with downloading attachments, I got a List of BodyPart objects which are actually attachments . The below function returns the list of BodyPart objects:

```
private List<BodyPart> getBodyParts(Message message) throws Exception     {
Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
// System.out.println(multipart.getCount());
List<BodyPart> result = new ArrayList<BodyPart>();
for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
    BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
    if(!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition()) &&
           !isNotBlank(bodyPart.getFileName())) {
        continue; // dealing with attachments only
    }
    else result.add(bodyPart);
}
return result;
```

}
I want to convert this List of BodyPart objects (i.e. List< BodyPart >result) to a List of Json Sting. I will highly appretiate any kind of help or suggestion.

I tried to convert BodyPart objects to Json object using com.google.gson.Gson in the below code section.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<String> resultJson;
List<String> resultJson = new ArrayList<String>();
for (BodyPart bodyPart : result) {
  String json = gson.toJson(bodyPart);
  resultJson.add(json);
}
```

But Faced the below error. Cant find out the exact reason properly.
Here is the 1st few line of stacktrace.

```
debugMessage":"java.lang.StackOverflowError","stackTrace":"java.lang.StackOverflowError
com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:371)
com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
```

Comment: Almost certainly you have circular reference in your data. You will have to fix that before serializing. I have read similar issues with Gson before. You could try Jackson instead, but if you indeed have a circular reference, it won't matter, unless you tell the serializer to ignore that.

Comment: I am quite new with java. Can you help me specifying the topics I need to know to apply the approaches you said. Or any tutorial link or example will be helpful. @dambros

Comment: Is BodyPart a custom class or Java's?

Comment: As I mentioned in the header, it is javax.mail.BodyPart class. @dambros

Comment: The problem is you cant serialize the BodyPart directly. You have to serialize its content. change your code to `String json = gson.toJson(bodyPart.getContent());` and tell me if that is the expected result please.

Comment: The line in above comment didn't solved the error. It is as same as before. @dambros

Comment: For a simple test I made here reading a string from the BodyPart, it worked. I guess I need to see the content of your BodyPart object to help you further.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the JSON version of the BodyParts to look like, given that the BodyParts can contain data of any kind?  Do you want the JSON form to contain the headers from the BodyParts along with the data from the BodyParts in the form of a byte array?  In the end I suspect you're going to have to write the JSON serializer for BodyParts yourself, so you'll get to decide how to represent all the data from the BodyParts in JSON.